How to allow generic function calls to leave out properties and arguments that could be undefined?
Basically, I want to have this structure:
type Config<TypeA extends object | undefined, TypeB extends object | undefined> = {
   typeA: TypeA,
   typeB: TypeB
}

type Parameter<MyObject extends object, MyConfig extends Config<any, any>> = Partial<MyConfig & {
  obj: MyObject
}>

type GenericClassResponse<MyObject extends object | undefined> = {
  obj?: MyObject
}

class MyGenericClass<_MyObject extends object | undefined, MyConfig extends Config<any, any>> {
  constructor(private config?: Partial<MyConfig>) {}

  // To make it compile, I had to add this as `value?` but I want this to be required in case MyObject or TypeA or TypeB are not undefined
  method(values?: Parameter<MyObject, MyConfig>): GenericClassResponse<MyObject> {
    return {
      obj: values?.obj
    }
  }
}

Then, I want to use it like this:
type MyObject = { a: number }
type OtherObject = { b: string }
type OtherType = { c: boolean }

function useMyGenericClassWithValues() {
  const instance = new MyGenericClass<MyObject, Config<OtherType, undefined>>({})
  instance.method({obj: {a: 0}, typeA: {c: true}}) // In this case, obj and typeA are not required, but they should be
}

And I want that the parameters obj and typeA to be required, because they were defined, but if they were never or  undefined they could be just ignored
For example:
const instance = new MyGenericClass<never, Config<never, never>>()
instance.method()
//or even
const instance = new MyGenericClass()
instance.method()

Since I didn't pass anything, I can call instance.method without any parameters because it wouldn't have anything.
Is it possible? how to do it?

Your examples have lots of missing types and syntax errors. When I tried to replicate your issue, I can't really https://tsplay.dev/wXx9Dw. Can you create a minimal reproducible example where I don't have to invent any types or values for you and has no syntax errors?

sure, I just added it as an small example, I will do it

I did like this, with some comments on what I really wanted, hopefully this is easier to understand now
Playground Link

I'd say you're trying to automatically change function parameters to allow someone to leave out any parameter which can be undefined, or is an object whose properties can all be undefined.  (I'd really recommend not using never for that; we already have undefined and never does not mean that.) Maybe something like the approach in this playground link meets your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

I'm trying to understand those types and apply to my real code, but thank you for trying to help me, I will let you know when I finish it

If I put that in your example code it looks like this. Not sure if that helps.

nice, but inside the method, I don't know how exactly to use args, it seems it's an array instead of an object and the code don't know what is the type of the array (or it assumes it's just {})

Inside the method, TS will never be smart enough to follow the kind of logic you're trying to express. Just make the inside see Partial | undefined, maybe as an overload to separate the outside from the inside, as shwon in this playground link. So does this meet your needs now? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's still missing?

yes, I think this is enough to write an answer, I didn't understand the logic yet, but it seems it's working here in most cases, thank you very much!

Please [edit] the question to summarize the specific question you have, rather than such a generic title that can be used for almost any question about generics and types in TypeScript. See [ask] for more tips on asking great questions.

TypeScript does not automatically allow undefined/empty things to be treated as optional. There have been feature requests like microsoft/TypeScript#12400, but they're not part of the language. If you want behavior like that, you'll have to implement it yourself, and be prepared for TypeScript not to "understand" what you're doing (e.g., it can't derive logical conclusions from your types).
Anyway, there are a bunch of pieces to this.

One thing you want is that in object types, you want any property for which undefined is a valid value to be optional.  So {a: string, b: number | undefined} should be treated like {a: string, b?: number}.  That lets you leave properties out that are "required" but accept undefined.
Let's write that type:
type UndefinablePropToOptional<T> = (Partial<T> & {
    [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K]
}) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

The idea is to take Partial<T> and intersect it with Pick<T, KeysOfTThatDoNotAcceptUndefined> using the Pick<T, K> utility type.  So UndefinablePropToOptional<{a: string, b: number | undefined}> should look like {a?: string, b?: number} & {a: string}. The intersection of a required property and an optional property is a required property.  Instead of defining KeysOfTThatDoNotAcceptUndefined, I use key remapping in mapped types to check each key and map any key where undefined extends T[K] to never, filtering them out.
And the part at the end with extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never really just collapses the intersection into a single object type, so for  {a?: string, b?: number} & {a: string} you get {a: string, b?: number} as desired:
type Z = UndefinablePropToOptional<{ a: string, b: number | undefined }>;
/* type Z = {
    a: string;
    b?: number | undefined;
} */


The next piece is to treat weak object types (that is, objects where every property is optional) as possibly undefined.  So you want to treat {a: string, b?: number} as-is, but {a?: string, b?: number} as {a?: string, b?: number} | undefined. That lets an undefined argument be treated like an empty object.
This one is a bit easier to write:
type WeakToUndefinable<T> =
    T | ({} extends T ? undefined : never)

All we're doing is using a conditional type to check if it's weak (if {} extends T then it means an empty object is accepted) and, if so, return a union with undefined. If not, then return a union with the never type since that doesn't change things:
type X = WeakToUndefinable<{ a: string, b?: number }>;
//   ^? type X = {a: string, b?: number} 
type Y = WeakToUndefinable<{ a?: string, b?: number }>;
//   ^? type Y = {a?: string, b?: number} | undefined


Finally, we want to take the tuple of function parameter types, and allow any element that accepts undefined to be an optional parameter. This is like UndefinablePropToOptional but trickier, because you can't have an optional parameter followed by a required one. This means you have to walk through the parameter tuple and keep it as-is until you reach an index where the rest of the arguments can be undefined, and then make the whole rest of the parameter list optional, with Partial.  That looks like this:
type UndefinableParamToOptional<T extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: undefined } extends T ? Partial<T> :
    T extends [any, ...infer R] ?
    T extends [...infer F, ...R] ?
    [...F, ...UndefinableParamToOptional<R>] : T : T;

It's a recursive conditional type using variadic tuple types to pick apart and put together the tuple.  First we check if mapping the tuple to a new tuple where each element is undefined would be an acceptable value for T. If so, then we return Partial<T> to make all the parameters optional. If not, then we grab the first element and recurse on the rest of the tuple.  Grabbing the first element in a way to preserve any tuple labels is an annoying two-step process. First we use conditional type inference to split the tuple into the first element and the rest of the tuple R, then we do another conditional type inference to infer a tuple type F that contains the first element (and the label), and spread that into the recursive part.  Yuck.
Let's test it:
type W = UndefinableParamToOptional<
    [a: string, b: number, c: boolean | undefined, d: Date,
        e: number | undefined, f: string | undefined]>;
/* type W = [a: string, b: number, c: boolean | undefined, d: Date, 
       e?: number | undefined, f?: string | undefined] */

You can see that everything starting with e is optional. The c parameter is not optional because d is required, and since there's no way to call a function and skip an argument, you need to pass in undefined anyway.

Finally we can put it all together. Take a tuple of parameter types, and for each element, make its undefined-accepting properties optional, and if this results in a weak object then allow that to be undefined too.  And then any trailing parameters which accept undefined are also made optional:
type UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional<T extends any[]> =
    UndefinableParamToOptional<{ [I in keyof T]: ({} | undefined | null) &
        WeakToUndefinable<UndefinablePropToOptional<T[I]>> }>;

This is just using all the previously-defined utility types. The type argument for UndefinableParamToOptional is a mapped type which applies WeakToUndefinable<UndefinablePropToOptional<?>> on each element. Oh, and I've intersected with {} | undefined | null, which is effectively a no-op (that union is equivalent to unknown and intersecting with unknown doesn't change things), but helps make the displayed types easier to read since it will eliminate some type alias names.
So let's finally see if this behaves as expected with some function:
declare const f: (...args: UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional<[
    a: { x: string, y: number | undefined },
    b: { x: boolean | undefined, y: Date | undefined },
    c: string | undefined,
]>) => void
/* const f: (
  a: { x: string; y?: number | undefined; }, 
  b?: {  x?: boolean | undefined; y?: Date | undefined; } | undefined, 
  c?: string | undefined) => void */

f({ x: "a" }); // okay
f({ x: "a", y: 123 }, {}); // okay
f({ x: "a" }, { y: new Date() }, "abc"); // okay
f({ x: "a" }, undefined, "def"); // okay

Great!

Now let's use that in your code:
class MyGenericClass<
    MyObject extends object | undefined = undefined,
    MyConfig extends Config<any, any> = Config<undefined, undefined>
> {
    constructor(private config?: Partial<MyConfig>) { }

    method(...args: UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional<[
        values: MyConfig & { obj: MyObject }]>): GenericClassResponse<MyObject>;

    method(values: Partial<MyConfig & { obj: MyObject }> = {}) {
        return {
            obj: values?.obj
        }
    }
}

So the call signature for method() applies our UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional to a single-element tuple of type  MyConfig & { obj: MyObject }.  Note that this is written as an overload, and the actual implementation just uses Partial for the type, because there's no way TypeScript can follow how that will pan out for a generic MyConfig and MyObject.
And I set the default type arguments for MyGenericClass to use undefined everywhere, so that if you leave out the type argument you get something that can be left out of the method().
Let's test it:
const instance = new MyGenericClass()
// const instance: MyGenericClass<undefined, Config<undefined, undefined>>
instance.method(); // okay
instance.method({}); // okay

and
const instance = new MyGenericClass<MyObject, Config<OtherType, undefined>>({})
instance.method({ obj: { a: 0 }, typeA: { c: true } }); // okay
instance.method({ obj: { a: 0 } }); // error
instance.method({ typeA: { c: true } }); // error

Looks good.

So, there you go. Now, it might be overkill to use UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional in this example; if you know you have just one method parameter, or certain things will never accept undefined, you can write something more specific. But UndefinableOrWeakPropsAndParamsToOptional is meant to be a more general-purpose transformation.
Playground link to code

this is an amazing explanation!
